# Add disclosure indicator arrow to the cells in search display controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

**Question:** How do I add disclosure indicator arrow to the cells in my search display controller?

In a **TableView** you would simply set up a prototype cell but it doesn't seem to be as straight forward for the cells inside a search display controller.

**BELOW IS THE TABLE VIEW CODE:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [dangerousItems count];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DangerousCell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [dangerousItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showDangerousItemDetail" sender: self];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDangerousItemDetail"]) {
        DangerousGoodsDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.dangerousItemName = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.dangerousItemImage = [dangerousImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.dangerousItemName = [dangerousItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.dangerousItemImage = [dangerousImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UISearchDisplayController` has a `searchResultsDataSource` property, which is a regular `UITableViewDataSource`. You are responsible for providing its implementation (typically, that's the original view controller to which the search display controller is attached).

The data source must implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is where you produce cells that represent results of the search. When you create a cell that needs a disclosure indicator, add that indicator in the accessory view before returning the cell from the method.

Comment: How do I programatically add a disclosure indicator to the cell?

Comment: @sephiith The usual way - `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` in viewing mode, or `cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;` in editing mode.

Comment: I have attempted to intergrate this with my current code. "    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier [accessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator]];" however that is giving me a undeclared identifer accessoryType.

Can you tell me how to intergrate it with "    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];" or if I am even suppose to add it to that.

Comment: @sephiith Just put `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;` on the line above `return cell;`.

Comment: I have done that. It added an arrow to the search box and made it unresponsive. (You can't click it)